# Using MinGW how can I create a file without the read-only file attribute?

Tags: c, windows-7, mingw

When I attempt to overwrite an existing file, I get a "permission denied" error.
I noticed that the file which is created has the "Read-only" attribute set. When I manually unset this I can then overwrite the file. Is there some flag I can pass to open() which will automatically unset this when I create a file?

Below is a bare bones example which illustrates the problem. The first run works, but the second produces the "permission denied" error.

Thanks,
Zach (New to MingW/Windows 7)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int fid;
    double data = 12.0;

    if ( (fid = open("junk.data", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_BINARY)) == -1 ) {
        printf("ERROR opening.\n\terror is:%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    write(fid, &data, sizeof(double));

    close(fid);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried both 0644 and S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR (with sys/stat.h included) and either works.

Make sure that you actually add it as third argument of open, instead as new term into the surrounding parentheses (as happened for me first, and compiles just fine)

Comment: I was pretty sure I had tried this (as the third argument), but I guess I must have been testing with an old version of the executable. It seems to be working now. -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`open` has a three-parameter variant:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

That third parameter allows you to specify the mode bits on Unix-type systems, but should be enough to set minimal r/w permissions on windows. (Check out the man page for details.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, but no dice.

Comment: humm... sorry about that. i'm sure there's a way without win32 calls, but I can't remember right now.

Comment: not a problem. As a kludge I can system("rm filename"). But it would be nice to know a more appropriate way to handle this. My code works fine in unix, but trying to get things going on windows is a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: slightly less kludgy is to use the `unlink` function. still not pretty, and as with anything of that order it's racy (file could be re-created between the `unlink` and `open` call).

Comment: I'll try that out. Raciness shouldn't be a problem in the current use case.

Comment: Well, unlink doesn't work, either. I had already tried remove(). They both puke "Permission denied".